# VB.NET - ThreadPool Queue Issues

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

*(This question has been almost completely re-written after I realised its an issue with the Threadpool not WebRequest Timeouts).*

*If you would like to test out my app for yourself download it by [clicking here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/jn1r0zm1x9w6c15/ProxyFuel.exe) and then click "Grab" then save it when it's finished. Then move onto the Checker tab and Import the file. Wait a bit and you will realize the issue if you read down below.*

---

I have an example file with 10,123 lines of Proxies - If I import it in my app with 700 threads (Doesn't seem to matter how many threads I set it to) and then wait for it to almost finish, It never will but will get to roughly 100 left to check and will just stop. This makes it incredibly hard to track when the threads are finished checking the Proxies or not (To enable save and re-import button).

**(The file I used below had about 13433 proxies and as you can see it got almost finished and ended)**
[image: 2]

(Showing that no new threads seem to be executing even though there are some left queued)
[image: 3]

Code: *(Slight Bit Newer)*

```
'Set a Variable to store the Proxies;
Dim proxies As New List(Of String)

Private Sub ImportButtonChecker_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ImportButtonChecker.Click

    'Create an Open File Dialog;
    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog

    'Get the Thread Count;
    Dim threads As Integer = CheckerThreads.Value

    ofd.RestoreDirectory = True
    ofd.Multiselect = False
    ofd.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    ofd.FilterIndex = 1
    ofd.ShowDialog()

    'If a file was Loaded Successfully;
    If (Not ofd.FileName = Nothing) Then

        'Disable the Import Button and Thread Count Box;
        ImportButtonChecker.Enabled = False
        CheckerThreads.Enabled = False

        'Read the file loaded by the OpenFileDialog;
        Using sr As New StreamReader(ofd.FileName)

            'Read the file;
            Dim file As String = sr.ReadToEnd

            'Regex;
            Dim regex As New Regex("[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{1,4}")

            'Get all the Proxies that was found from the Regex Condition;
            Dim matches As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(file)

            'For Each of the Proxies found from the Regex Condition, Add them to the List of Proxies;
            For Each proxy As Match In matches
                proxies.Add(proxy.ToString)
            Next

        End Using

        'Set the Thread Count;
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(threads, threads)
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(threads, threads)
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = threads
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True

        'For Each proxy from the Opened File;
        For Each Proxy In proxies

            'Check the Proxy;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf CheckProxy), Proxy)

        Next

    End If

End Sub

Private Function CheckProxy(ByVal Proxy As String) As String

    Try

        'Set the WebRequest URL to Google while setting the UserAgent, Timeout and of course the Proxy;
        Dim init As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com")
        init.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36"
        init.Timeout = 4500
        init.ReadWriteTimeout = 8000
        init.Proxy = New WebProxy(Proxy)

        'Initiate the WebRequest and see if the Proxy can connect fine;
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = init.GetResponse()

        'Since no Exception has Occured as the Proxy as a Working Proxy;
        ValidProxies.Items.Add(Proxy)

        'Autoscroll;
        ValidProxies.TopIndex = ValidProxies.Items.Count - 1

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Autoscroll;
        ValidProxies.TopIndex = ValidProxies.Items.Count - 1

        Return False

    Finally

        'Add it as a Checked Proxy;
        CheckedProxies.Items.Add(Proxy)

        Label3.Text = "Checked: " + CheckedProxies.Items.Count.ToString + " Total: " + proxies.Count.ToString

        'Increment the Progress Bar's Value;
        CheckerGroup.Text = "Valid: " + ValidProxies.Items.Count.ToString + " - Checked: " + CheckedProxies.Items.Count.ToString

        'If it's finished;
        If CheckedProxies.Items.Count.ToString = proxies.Count.ToString Then

            'Re-Enable to Import and Save button;
            ImportButtonChecker.Enabled = True
            SaveButtonChecker.Enabled = True

        End If

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: maybe the delay is due to your own code (e.g. some work are done before/after request so taking more time)

Comment: @Kilanny Nope, The code above is the only code being executed.

Comment: from your question `Roughly 40sec. per 1,000 executions` seems to be natural. Because web request needs some time to initiate the connection to server (relatively small). That time when summed can be 40 second in your case

Comment: I guess google servers block high-rate request, because they ofcourse cause performance impact on their servers. So when they discover your IP repeatedly calls them very fast, they block you some time.

Comment: How may proxies do you use? If they are 10 proxies for example, they can be easily detected and blocked as high-requesting IPs

Comment: @Kilanny Well the amount can be chosen by the user but either way no they cant, Thats the whole point of proxies, If you connect from different proxies its basically connecting from different internet providers/ip's so they cant track that.

Comment: Still need help with this and I think its just straight up not Queueing all of th e Foreach's or something as I did many different methods to check and the Count is definitely correct. Any help would be great. I'll upload the current build you can test it yourself.

Comment: The build is in the Original Post - I also updated it a bit and slightly updated the code.

Comment: Still need help...

Comment: Seriously, No one has any ideas?

Comment: Again still need help on this - Still happening :/

Comment: No one has any clue?